# How can I automate data frame naming in R?

Tags: r, function, batch-processing, subset

Let's say I have the following data frame:

```
x <- data.frame(let = sample(LETTERS, 100, replace = T),
                num = sample(1:10, 100, replace = T))
```

I want to create several subsets of `x` where each new data frame is named after the levels of `x$let`. So far, I've come up with this simple function:

```
ss <- function(letra){
  return(subset(x, let == letra))
}
```

Which is very rudimentary and doesn't do the naming as I wanted. My question is: **how can I automate the following procedure?**

```
a <- ss('A')
b <- ss('B')
c <- ss('C')
...
z <- ss('Z')
```

Comment: While this is certainly possible, it's not a good practice. Would you mind storing all subsets in a list instead of each in a separate variable?

Comment: The answer likely is, "don't". Use `x <- lapply(LETTERS, ss)` instead.

Comment: ...or possibly just `split(x,x$let)`.

Comment: The thing is that in the end I'll have to e-mail each subset as a XLS file to a different person. Will storing the subsets in a list allow me to do that?

Comment: Not only will it allow it, it will make is _easier_.

Comment: Nice. Would you mind elaborating it further as an answer? May just be the solution I was looking for!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To elaborate a bit.

```
xs <- split(x, x$let)
```

Now we have a list, `xs`, of each subset of the original data frame. The names of each list component matches the factor level it was selected on:

```
 xs[['D']]
   let num
8    D   8
14   D   1
16   D   9
54   D   5
60   D   6
64   D   8
74   D   8
```

Most people use either **xlsx** or **XLConnect** to write Excel files from R. I happen to use **XLConnect**, but the solutions would be very similar.

Now we can simply do this:

```
require(XLConnect)
file_name <- paste0("file",LETTERS,".xlsx")

for (i in seq_len(length(xs))){
    wb <- loadWorkbook(file_name[i],create = TRUE)
    createSheet(wb,"Sheet1")
    writeWorksheet(wb,data = xs[[i]],sheet = 1)
    saveWorkbook(wb)
}
```

I've done this in a `for` loop so that it's easier to read and understand, but obviously this could all be shoved into an `lapply` or `mapply` type solution as well.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I confess I don't use lists a lot. Using XLConnect gives me an error ("Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘writeWorksheet’ for signature ‘"workbook", "data.frame", "missing"’"), but I think it has something to do with a faulty Java installation. Until I work it out with the IT guys, I'm exporting to CSV and letting my recipients deal with it. :D

Comment: @wleoncio Not your fault, totally mine! I wrote that without testing it fully and forgot the `createSheet` line and also that you need to specify a sheet in `whiteWorksheet`. Assuming your Java installation is ok, the edited version should work. (Although Java _is_ a pain in the butt.)

Comment: Right! Works like a charm now. It runs slower than `read.csv`, but will definitely save me a lot of time in the long run. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with Joshua that you may want to do something different, but if you're really hooked on your previous idea, you can use:

```
x <- data.frame(let = sample(LETTERS, 100, replace = T),
            num = sample(1:10, 100, replace = T))

ss <- function(letra){
    assign(letra, subset(x, let == letra), envir = .GlobalEnv)

    # Returning the DF is optional:
    # return(subset(x, let == letra))
}
ss('A')
print(A)
```

Update: taking Joran's suggestion, one can write:

```
x_split <- split(x,x$let)
for (let in x_split) {
  write.csv(let, file = paste0((let$let)[1], ".csv"))
}
```